# while loops within expect

Tags: bash, while-loop, expect

I am using expect within bash. I want my script to telnet into a box, expect a prompt, send a command. If there is a different prompt now, it has to proceed or else it has to send that command again.
My script goes like this:

```
\#!bin/bash  
//I am filling up IP and PORT1 here  
expect -c "    
set timeout -1  
spawn telnet $IP $PORT1  
sleep 1  
send \"\r\"  
send \"\r\"  
set temp 1  
while( $temp == 1){    
expect {  
Prompt1 { send \"command\" }  
Prompt2 {send \"Yes\"; set done 0}  
}  
}  
"
```

Output:

```
invalid command name "while("  
    while executing  
"while( == 1){"
```

Kindly help me.
I tried to change it to  `while [ $temp == 1] {`

I am still facing the error below:

Output:

```
invalid command name "=="  
    while executing  
"== 1"  
    invoked from within  
"while [  == 1] {  
expect {
```

Comment: You might want to first write a pure expect script while debugging this issue so you don't have shell quoting rules potentially changing your expect script in subtle ways.

Comment: What's happening with the weird-looking errors: because your script is double quoted, the shell (not expect) is substituting `$temp` with a null value.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is how I'd implement this:

```
expect -c '
  set timeout -1  
  spawn telnet [lindex $argv 0] [lindex $argv 1]  
  send "\r"  
  send "\r"  
  expect {  
    Prompt1 {
      send "command"
      exp_continue
    }  
    Prompt2 {
      send "Yes\r"
    }  
  }  
}  
'  $IP $PORT1
```

- use single quotes around the expect script to protect expect variables
- pass the shell variables as arguments to the script.
- use "exp_continue" to loop instead of an explicit while loop (you had the wrong terminating variable name anyway)

Comment: It worked!! Thanks a ton!!But had one query, when we put exp_continue, does it send "command" again if it did not see the prompt2?? I mean in a loop. Or sends command once and keeps waiting for prompt2?

Comment: When it sees Prompt1, it will send the command, then go back to the top of the expect block and wait for either Prompt1 or Prompt2. When it sees Prompt2, it sends Yes and just falls out of the block.

Answer (score 4):

The syntax for while is "while test body". There must be a spce between each of those parts which is why you get the error "no such command while)"

Also, because of tcl quoting rules, 99.99% of the time the test needs to be in curly braces. So, the syntax is:

```
while {$temp == 1} {
```

For more information see http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/while.htm

(you probably have other problems related to your choice of shell quotes; this answer addresses your specific question about the while statement)